# How to implement searching concept using keywords in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can anyone guide how to implement the keyword search concept in SQL.Is there only “Like” operator  available or any other options there?

Example:      -                 Table:

**Keyword** --      **Questions**        --      **Answers**

- Where,pen        --   Where is my pen?  --  Pen is on the table
- Where ,pen, kept -- where you have kept the pen  -- Pen is under the 
  table

Input  - Where is my pen?
Output should be  - “Pen is on the table”

In this part I have to split the keyword from input and check the keyword with db to send the output. I should  get only one output from above  .Because in second  row value  also have  “where,pen” keyword

Could anyone suggest  how this logic  will be implemented .
I would like to know If any keyword creating option can done in SQL part itself.

Comment: What's wrong with `LIKE`?

Comment: You may wish to learn FULL TEXT option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search

Comment: You can try PATINDEX https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql

Comment: PATINDEX - It provides return only position of the string know.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to store the keywords in a comma separated list.  Instead, you want a separate table, say `QuestionKeywords`:

```
create table QuestionKeywords (
    QuestionKeywordsId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    QuestionId int not null references Questions(QuestionId),
    Keyword varchar(255),
    constraint unq_QuestionKeywords_QuestionId_Keyword unique (QuestionId, Keyword)
);
```

You can then search for keywords just using equality or `in`.

Comment: Could you please explain with example?.Because I would like to know any option is there to find the keyword from the input question's?

Comment: Gordon, where is the data type of `QuestionKeywordsId` column?